# Previous/next expression in ssrs translated from crystal reports

Tags: reporting-services, crystal-reports, ssrs-2012

I got this expression:

```
=Switch(Fields!Kod.Value=1, "text",
Fields!Kod.Value=2, "text",
Fields!Kod.Value=3, "text",
Fields!Kod.Value=4, "text",
Previous(Fields!Kod.Value) = 4 and (Fields!Kod.Value = 5 or 
Fields!Kod.Value = 6 or fields!Kod.Value = 7 or 
fields!Kod.Value=8), "more text",
Fields!Kod.Value=5, "   text",
Fields!Kod.Value=6, "   text",
Fields!Kod.Value=7, "   text",
Fields!Kod.Value=8, "   text",
Fields!Kod.Value=9, "text")
```

This row

```
 Previous(Fields!Kod.Value) = 4 and (Fields!Kod.Value = 5 or Fields!Kod.Value = 6 or fields!Kod.Value = 7 or fields!Kod.Value=8)
```

is resulting in an error:

*"The scope parameter must be set to a string constant that is equal to either the name of a containing group, the name of a containting data region, or the name of a dataset"*

The problematic row is a try of translating this crystal reports formula which is from a supress:

```
if {SP;1.Kod} = 4 and 
(next({SP;1.Kod})=5 or
next({SP;1.Kod})=6 or
next({SP;1.Kod})=7 or
next({SP;1.Kod})=8
)
 then false
else true
```

But I was thinking that I could put these two formulas together and get the "more text" to show if previous(kod=4) And next(kod) = 5, 6, 7, 8.

How can I make this expression work? Or am I doing this the wrong way?

Comment: More details about the report design like screenshots, data, groups etc. maybe would help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so thanks to this site 
https://www.codykonior.com/2011/04/04/duh-moments-previous-and-cross-apply/
and Alans answere above
we finally did it!

He explains that when the row is in a group it doesn't know which instance off the group to get the previous from. Adding First() to the expression worked.

```
Previous(First(Fields!X.Value),"Group")
```

Thanks for the help in the comments and I hope this helpes someone!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a scope to the previous function. For example this might just be your dataset name (it can also be group names etc) like this.

```
PREVIOUS(Fields!Kod.Value, "dataset1")
```

**Note:** The quotes **are** required.

Comment: It can be ommited in most cases, but it seems he is using the expression on group summary row, where scope must be defined

Comment: The expression is in a stepped table at the inner group. The table has 3 groups in total. I tried all three and the dataset ( very cautious about the big/ small letters), still get the same error :/ the previous expressin part gets redmarked.

Comment: Try isolating the problem, by assigning the expression on one group textbox each time.

Comment: @niktrs how do you mean? Like see where the problem is?

Comment: If you use the expression eg. in 3 textboxes, leave the expression initially only on the first, check if the report is executing, continue on the second,...

Comment: Hmm,  when I write "Tablix2" as the scope it still shows red but I can atleast show the report which is something (though the row acts a bit strange). @niktrs

Comment: This seems to be working Previous(First(Fields!Kod.Value), "Kod")
Got it from here: https://www.codykonior.com/2011/04/04/duh-moments-previous-and-cross-apply/